# How a dialog fragment set result to other fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a `fragment` that has a `button`.

When I click on button the system opens a `dialog fragment` where the user can choose some info.
In the dialog there is a button "Ok". When the user clicks on ok, the dialog dismisses and we return on the other `fragment`.

I want to return to the other `fragment` with the result(the info choosen).

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several way to achieve this:
You can save the result from the Dialog in the activity (getActivity()) and get in from the other Fragment

You can let the base Fragment implement a callback interface and call its callback function when pressing OK from the Dialog. You'll need to pass the interface (probably it'll be "this") as an argument when creating the Dialog Fragment.

Hope this helps.

Comment: and if in the dialog when press ok i use getsupportfragmentmanager.findfragmentbytag("tagmainfragment").setresult ? (set result is a method of main fragment)

Comment: This could work.. I meant that you'll pass the main fragment as an argument to the dialog fragment.

Comment: pass the result to the activty is ok. but then how can main fragment know that the dialog has set the result in the activity ? i want that the istant that i press "oK" IN THE DIalog, the main fragment save the data set in the dialog